# How to create multiple radio button using for loop in php?

Tags: php, html

Question:- I want to retrieve questions from database and it should be followed by 2 radio buttons for every question. I did, but suppose when I click on YES button for 1st question I can't select YES button for 2nd question so how can I do it?

```
<?
$query      = "SELECT mq_question FROM mental_questions where mq_agegroup=4 ";
$result     = mysql_query($query);
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 
Print "<ol>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<h4><font color=#336699><li>{$row['mq_question']} </li></font><h4/><br/>";    
    echo "<p><font color=#336699>Yes<input type='radio' value='yes' id='yes' name='yes' />No<input type='radio' value='no' id='no' name='no' /></font></p></br>"; 
}
Print "</ol>";
?>
```

Comment: Do you have to pay for every character you type?

Comment: @user615758: Your PHP isn't efficient, but that isn't the problem with your question.  There are several errors and styling problems in your HTML.  I've retagged your question as "HTML", but I can't edit your question without obfuscating the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note the `name` of each radio button:

```
<?php

  $questions = array('q1', 'q2', 'q3');
  echo "<ol>";

  foreach ($questions as $i=>$question) {
    echo "<li>$question<br/>"; 
    echo "Yes<input type='radio' value='yes' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";
    echo "No<input type='radio' value='no' name='answer-$i' /></li>";
  }

  echo "</ol>";

?>
```

Comment: hay thanks buddy...i solved by this code<?php
   $all_qs = "<table>";
   for ($i_hp=1;$i_hp<$total_rows+1;$i_hp++) {
   if($i_hp % 2) { $format = '#666666'; $bgcolor='#bbdaf7';} else { $format = '#333333'; $bgcolor='#aed4f7';}
   $hp_name = 'mhtq' . $i_hp . '_yes_label';
   $hp_name_inp = 'mhtq' . $i_hp . '_yes_input';
   $all_qs .= '<tr bgcolor='.$bgcolor.'><td><label><font color='.$format.'>'.$$hp_name.'</font></label></td><td width="200">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$$hp_name_inp.'</td></tr>';
   }
   $all_qs .= '</table>';

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is out of date, but I had the same problem for a couple of days and just found a very simple solution.
Try adding a new INT AUTO INCREMENT column in your database, and placing it as name for radio button. All the rows will have different names and radio buttons will work. 
Something like this:

`...
"<td>Da li je kontakt ostvaren?<br/><label><input type='radio' name=$row[ID] value='Da'/> DA </label><label><input type='radio' name=$row[ID] value='Ne'/> NE</label></td>";`

`"<td>Da li je predmet poslat?<br/><label><input type='radio' name=$row[ID] value='Da'/> DA </label><label><input type='radio' name=$row[ID] value='Ne'/> NE</label></td>";`

`"<td>Da li je saradnja zavrsena?<br/><label><input type='radio' name=$row[ID] value='Da'/> DA</label><label><input type='radio' name=$row[ID] value='Ne'/> NE</label></td>";`
... `

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the "name" argument to a unique qualifier for each row
The "values" for each will be "yes" and "no"
But the "name" arguments need to be different

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution I found

```
<?php
    $all_qs = "<table>";
    for ($i_hp=1;$i_hp<$total_rows+1;$i_hp++) {
        if($i_hp % 2) { 
          $format = '#666666'; $bgcolor='#bbdaf7';
        } else { 
          $format = '#333333'; 
          $bgcolor='#aed4f7';
        }
        $hp_name = 'mhtq' . $i_hp . '_yes_label';
        $hp_name_inp = 'mhtq' . $i_hp . '_yes_input';
        $all_qs .= 
          '<tr bgcolor=' . $bgcolor .
          '><td><label><font color=' . $format . 
          '>' . $$hp_name . 
          '</font></label></td><td width="200">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $$hp_name_inp . 
          '</td></tr>';
    }
    $all_qs .= '</table>';
```